# How should I use the h5py library for storing time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytables, h5py

I have some time series data that i previously stored as hdf5 files using `pytables`. I recently tried storing the same with `h5py` lib. However, since all elements of `numpy` array have to be of same dtype, I have to convert the date (which is usually the index) into '`float64`' type before storing it using `h5py` lib. **When I use `pytables`, the index and its dtype are preserved which makes it possible for me to query the time-series without the need of pulling it all in the memory. I guess with `h5py` that is not possible. am I missing something here?** And if not, under what situations should i use `h5py` lib to store time series data? I ask this question cause, clarity on this could help me design a more efficient (processing & storage wise) project.

below is simple code, where I have to lose index information in order to store it as a single dtype object

```
dt_range = pd.date_range('2016-12-01','2016-12-10')
data = np.arange(0,20).reshape(-1,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = dt_range, columns = list('ab'), dtype = 'float')
df.index  = df.index.to_julian_date()
df = df.reset_index()
h = h5py.File(r'path\temp.h5', 'w')
dset = h.create_dataset('temp',data = df.values, shape = (10,3))
```

Comment: Can you read the files created by 'tables' with 'h5py'?

Comment: I am not sure i did this correctly, but although 'h5py' can recognize the file created through 'pytables' (eg: h.keys() command), when I try to read the same (eg: h['pytable-filename'][:]), it throws this error: 'AttributeError: 'slice' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I haven't worked with `pytables`.  `h5py` makes the file dataseries look and behave like `numpy` arrays.  That's what your `df.values` is saving.  You may need to extract the pandas indexing to an array as well, and write that.  Do you know much of `numpy`, or just `pandas`?

Comment: The pandas indexing might be writeable as a `h5` dimension scale, but I haven't worked with that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use pandas `to_hdf`

```
dt_range = pd.date_range('2016-12-01','2016-12-10')
data = np.arange(0,20).reshape(-1,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = dt_range, columns = list('ab'), dtype = 'float')
df.index  = df.index.to_julian_date()
df = df.reset_index()

with pd.HDFStore('temp.h5', 'w') as h:
    df.to_hdf(h, 'temp')

pd.read_hdf('temp.h5', 'temp')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I run `@piRSquared` code, and look at the file with `h5py` I see:

```
In [4]: import h5py
In [5]: f=h5py.File('temp.h5')

In [8]: list(f.keys())
Out[8]: ['temp']
In [9]: f['temp']
Out[9]: <HDF5 group "/temp" (4 members)>
In [10]: list(f['temp'].keys())
Out[10]: ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values']

In [11]: f['temp']['axis0'][:]
Out[11]: 
array([b'index', b'a', b'b'], 
      dtype='|S5')
In [12]: f['temp']['axis1'][:]
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
In [13]: f['temp']['block0_items'][:]
Out[13]: 
array([b'index', b'a', b'b'], 
      dtype='|S5')
In [14]: f['temp']['block0_values'][:]
Out[14]: 
array([[  2.45772350e+06,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  2.45772450e+06,   2.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00],
       [  2.45772550e+06,   4.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00],
       [  2.45772650e+06,   6.00000000e+00,   7.00000000e+00],
       [  2.45772750e+06,   8.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00],
       [  2.45772850e+06,   1.00000000e+01,   1.10000000e+01],
       [  2.45772950e+06,   1.20000000e+01,   1.30000000e+01],
       [  2.45773050e+06,   1.40000000e+01,   1.50000000e+01],
       [  2.45773150e+06,   1.60000000e+01,   1.70000000e+01],
       [  2.45773250e+06,   1.80000000e+01,   1.90000000e+01]])
```

So it has saved the indexing information in 3 series, and the values in another, which loads as a 2d numpy array.

That's the same kind of information that I'd expect to see from a file created by `pytables`.

According to it's documentation, `pd.HDFStore` is using `pytables`.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned in the question that i use pytables, actually i use pytables through 'pd.HDFStore' function. Pretty much the same way as solution provided by @piRSquared. But my real query is, if instead I use h5py, since i lose the date dtype information in the process, I cannot query my object -say, base on date range- like i can using pd.HDFStore.

Comment: What I got back via `h5py` are arrays.  I didn't show the `attrs` of the group and series.  Presumably with `h5py` I can read everything needed to recreate a DataFrame that roughly matches the source, and would allow me to `query` it as you want.  `HDFStore` is taking care of the details that you'd have to handle explicitly if using `h5py`.