# h5py: column names without using compound dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

Is there a way to have column names in a HDF5 dataset (created by `h5py`) without having to use a `numpy.ndarray` as data structure?

I am thinking about something like the following for a dataset with `N` rows and `M` columns:

```
with h5py.File("foo.h5py", "w") as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset("bar", (N, M), dtype='int8', ...)

    # Access columns via (of course, having defined the names somewhere before)
    dset['col0'] = ... # equivalent to dset[:,0]
```

So: there would need to be a way to pass the column names to the dataset and specify an axis they belong to.

Is that possible? I am basically looking for a functionality similar to those of a structured numpy array, but as a hdf5-native data type (i.e. without the numpy array).

(It's probably something obvious, but I am a bit stuck...)

---

**Context**: I would like to be able to easily resize the dataset, and with h5py this is really easy: e.g. `dset.resize(num_columns + 1, axis=1)` for adding a new column.
With a structured `numpy` array, it would not be so easy (I would e.g. need `append_fields(...)` from `np.lib.recfunctions` and quite some logic to add a column), which is why I would like to avoid this approach.

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary mapping from name to column index?  Or list of names with a list `find`?  A structured array must do something like that, doing a lookup in `dtype.names`.  Are the names essential to the problem, or just a coding convenience?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41173254/901925 to get an idea of how `pytables` stores a pandas dataframe in hdf5.  Row and column names are stored in separate data series, while the data is a 2d array.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your comment! I already have a dictionary-to-column mapping, but I need to save the column names alongside the data and it appears to me to be the most elegant solution to have the columns named directly. …your argument that there needs to be some kind of lookup seems reasonable though.