# HDF5 and Python: Automatic export of an object

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm new to the HDF5 file format and have been experimenting successfully in Python with h5py.  Now its time to store real data.
I will need to store a list of objects, where each object can be one of several types and each type will have a number of arrays and strings.  The critical part is that the list of objects will be different for each file, and there will be hundreds of files.
Is there a way to automatically export an arbitrary, nested object into (and back from) an HDF5 file?  I'm imagining a routine that would automatically span the hierarchy of a nested object and build the same hierarchy in the HDF5 file.
I've read through the H5PY doc and don't see any spanning routines.  Furthermore, google and SO searches are (strangely) not showing this capability.  Am i missing something or is there another way to look at this.

Comment: You'll have to give a more concrete example.  Your description doesn't match my limited experience with `h5py`.  That interface handles `numpy` arrays, especially the numeric and string dtypes.  Also it can handle structured arrays.  I don't `object` dtype arrays can be saved.  It does not interface with Python objects in general.  `np.save` with `pickling` can store a wider mix of Python objects.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will have a `dict` of items, with each item containing a `class` (struct) of `ndarrays`, `floats` and `strings`.  It was my thought that a Python routine could scan the nested object (tree) from the top (root) and follow the hierarchy to each data primitive (each leaf).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173254/how-should-i-use-h5py-lib-for-storing-time-series-data explores how `pytables` stores a `pandas` dataframe in a `hdf5`, and what it looks like via `h5py`.  That's the most complex structure I've seen in `h5py`.

Comment: Have you  experimented with use `pickle` with this object?

Comment: @hpaulj: Not yet.  I was looking for a binary export for large ndarrays and assumed the `pickle` wasn't the right approach.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks about `pandas`.  I will look into that.