# pytables writes much faster than h5py. Why?

Tags: python, h5py, pytables

I noticed that writing .h5 files takes much longer if I use the h5py library instead of the pytables library. What is the reason? This is also true when the shape of the array is known before. Further, i use the same chunksize and no compression filter.

The following script:

```
import h5py
import tables
import numpy as np
from time import time

dim1, dim2 = 64, 1527416

# append columns
print("PYTABLES: append columns")
print("=" * 32)
f = tables.open_file("/tmp/test.h5", "w")
a = f.create_earray(f.root, "time_data", tables.Float32Atom(), shape=(0, dim1))
t1 = time()
zeros = np.zeros((1, dim1), dtype="float32")
for i in range(dim2):
    a.append(zeros)
tcre = round(time() - t1, 3)
thcre = round(dim1 * dim2 * 4 / (tcre * 1024 * 1024), 1)
print("Time to append %d columns: %s sec (%s MB/s)" % (i+1, tcre, thcre))
print("=" * 32)
chunkshape = a.chunkshape
f.close()

print("H5PY: append columns")
print("=" * 32)
f = h5py.File(name="/tmp/test.h5",mode='w')
a = f.create_dataset(name='time_data',shape=(0, dim1),
                     maxshape=(None,dim1),dtype='f',chunks=chunkshape)
t1 = time()
zeros = np.zeros((1, dim1), dtype="float32")
samplesWritten = 0
for i in range(dim2):
    a.resize((samplesWritten+1, dim1))
    a[samplesWritten:(samplesWritten+1),:] = zeros
    samplesWritten += 1
tcre = round(time() - t1, 3)
thcre = round(dim1 * dim2 * 4 / (tcre * 1024 * 1024), 1)
print("Time to append %d columns: %s sec (%s MB/s)" % (i+1, tcre, thcre))
print("=" * 32)
f.close()
```

returns on my computer:

```
PYTABLES: append columns
================================
Time to append 1527416 columns: 22.679 sec (16.4 MB/s)
================================
H5PY: append columns
================================
Time to append 1527416 columns: 158.894 sec (2.3 MB/s)
================================
```

If I flush after every for loop, like:

```
for i in range(dim2):
    a.append(zeros)
    f.flush()
```

I get:

```
PYTABLES: append columns
================================
Time to append 1527416 columns: 67.481 sec (5.5 MB/s)
================================
H5PY: append columns
================================
Time to append 1527416 columns: 193.644 sec (1.9 MB/s)
================================
```

Comment: This is likely due to a very high library overhead. If you write eg. chunks of 256,64 at once you should be >150 MB/s

Answer (score 19):

This is an interesting comparison of **PyTables** and **h5py** write performance. Typically I use them to read HDF5 files (and usually with a few reads of large datasets), so haven't noticed this difference.  My thoughts align with @max9111: that performance should improve as the number of write operations decreased as the size of the written dataset increased. To that end, I reworked your code to write N lines of data using fewer loops. (Code is at the end).
Results were surprising (to me). Key findings:
 1. Total time to write all of the data was a linear function of the # of loops (for both PyTables and h5py).
 2. The performance difference between PyTables and h5py only improved slightly as dataset I/O size increased.
 3. Pytables was 5.4x faster writing 1 row at a time (1,527,416 writes), and was 3.5x faster writing 88 rows at a time (17,357 writes).

Here is a plot comparing performance.
[image: Chart of Performance Comparison]
Chart with values for table above.
[image: Performance Benchmark Data]

Also, I noticed your code comments say "append columns", but you are extending the first dimension (rows of a HDF5 table/dataset). I rewrote your code to test performance extending the second dimension (adding columns to the HDF5 file), and saw very similar performance.

Initially I thought the I/O bottleneck was due to resizing the datasets. So, I rewrote the example to initially size the array to hold the all rows. *This did NOT improve performance (and significantly degraded h5py performance).* That was very surprising. Not sure what to make of it.

Here is my example. It uses 3 variables that size the array (as data is added):

- cdim: # of columns (fixed)
- row_loops: # of write loops
- block_size: size of data block written on each loop
- row_loops*block_size = total number of rows written

I also made a small change to the add Ones instead of Zeros (to  verify data was written, and moved it to the top (and out of the timing loops).

**My code here:**

```
import h5py
import tables
import numpy as np
from time import time

cdim, block_size, row_loops = 64, 4, 381854 
vals = np.ones((block_size, cdim), dtype="float32")

# append rows
print("PYTABLES: append rows: %d blocks with: %d rows" % (row_loops, block_size))
print("=" * 32)
f = tables.open_file("rowapp_test_tb.h5", "w")
a = f.create_earray(f.root, "time_data", atom=tables.Float32Atom(), shape=(0, cdim))
t1 = time()
for i in range(row_loops):
    a.append(vals)
tcre = round(time() - t1, 3)
thcre = round(cdim * block_size * row_loops * 4 / (tcre * 1024 * 1024), 1)
print("Time to append %d rows: %s sec (%s MB/s)" % (block_size * row_loops, tcre, thcre))
print("=" * 32)
chunkshape = a.chunkshape
f.close()

print("H5PY: append rows %d blocks with: %d rows" % (row_loops, block_size))
print("=" * 32)
f = h5py.File(name="rowapp_test_h5.h5",mode='w')
a = f.create_dataset(name='time_data',shape=(0, cdim),
                     maxshape=(block_size*row_loops,cdim),
                     dtype='f',chunks=chunkshape)
t1 = time()
samplesWritten = 0
for i in range(row_loops):
    a.resize(((i+1)*block_size, cdim))
    a[samplesWritten:samplesWritten+block_size] = vals
    samplesWritten += block_size
tcre = round(time() - t1, 3)
thcre = round(cdim * block_size * row_loops * 4 / (tcre * 1024 * 1024), 1)
print("Time to append %d rows: %s sec (%s MB/s)" % (block_size * row_loops, tcre, thcre))
print("=" * 32)
f.close()
```

Comment: Very nice answer!  The chunk-size is also to small to get good results. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961222/4045774 In this case not really relevant, because the questioner didn't ask about how to read the data, but in general the chunk-chache size has also to be set to get good performance https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/4045774 In the meantime the functionallity of h5py_cache was added to h5py.

Comment: Handy references on chunk sizing. Thanks. You mention '_h5py_cache was added to h5py_'. Is it implemented with the `rdcc_*` parameters?

Comment: Yes, these are the parameters.

Comment: The size of your biggest blocks (88 * 64) is still pretty small. I continued it to blocks of (4096 * 64) numbers - 1 MiB of data - at which point the difference between h5py & pytables shrinks to about 2%.