# How to write a Pandas Dataframe into a HDF5 dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to write data from a Pandas dataframe into a nested hdf5 file, with multiple groups and datasets within each group. I'd like to keep it as a single file which will grow in the future on a daily basis. I've had a go with the following code, which shows the structure of what I'd like to achieve

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = h5py.File('database.h5','w')

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d) 
        
groups = ['A','B','C']         
        
for m in groups:
    
    group = file.create_group(m)
    dataset = ['1','2','3']

    for n in dataset:
    
        data = df
        ds = group.create_dataset(m + n, data.shape)
        print ("Dataset dataspace is", ds.shape)
        print ("Dataset Numpy datatype is", ds.dtype)
        print ("Dataset name is", ds.name)
        print ("Dataset is a member of the group", ds.parent)
        print ("Dataset was created in the file", ds.file)
                        
        print ("Writing data...")
        ds[...] = data        
     
        print ("Reading data back...")
        data_read = ds[...]
            
        print ("Printing data...")
        print (data_read)

file.close()
```

This way the nested structure is created but it loses the index and columns. I've tried the

```py
df.to_hdf('database.h5', ds, table=True, mode='a')
```

but didn't work, I get this error

> AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'split'

Can anyone shed some light please. Many thanks

Comment: `pandas` uses `pytables` to write data frames to `hdf5` files.  There are SO questions looking a those files with `h5py`.  As I recall the layout is complex, but not impossible to follow.  `h5py` is essentially `numpy` iterface to to `hdf5`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173254/how-should-i-use-h5py-lib-for-storing-time-series-data

Answer (score 4):

[df.to_hdf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) expects a string as a `key` parameter (second parameter):

> **key** : string
>
> identifier for the group in the store

so try this:

```
df.to_hdf('database.h5', ds.name, table=True, mode='a')
```

where `ds.name` should return you a string (key name):

```
In [26]: ds.name
Out[26]: '/A1'
```

Comment: The source for this calls `pytables.to_hdf`.

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, it calls `pandas.io.pytables.to_hdf()`, but i don't understand what did you want to say/show...

Comment: @MaxU I've tried the ds.name in the keys but doesn't work as it still loses columns and indexes and moreover it returns all zeros

Answer (score 3):

I thought to have a go with pandas\pytables and the HDFStore class instead of h5py. So I tried the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

db = pd.HDFStore('Database.h5')

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=index, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

groups = ['A','B','C']     

i = 1    

for m in groups:

    subgroups = ['d','e','f']

    for n in subgroups:

        db.put(m + '/' + n, df, format = 'table', data_columns = True)
```

It works, 9 groups (groups instead of datasets in pyatbles instead fo h5py?) created from A/d to C/f. Columns and indexes preserved and can do the dataframe operations I need. Still wondering though whether this is an efficient way to retrieve data from a specific group which will become huge in the the future i.e. operations like

```
db['A/d'].Col1[4:]
```