# save multiple pd.DataFrames with hierarchy to hdf5

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have multiple pd.DataFrames which have hierarchical organization. Let's say I have:

```
day_temperature_london_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
night_temperature_london_df = pd.DataFrame(...)

day_temperature_paris_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
night_temperature_paris_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
```

And I want to group them into hdf5 file so two of them go to group 'london' and two of others go to 'paris'.

If I use h5py I lose the format of the `pd.DataFrame`, lose indexes and columns.

```
f = h5py.File("temperature.h5", "w")
grp_london = f.create_group("london")
day_lon_dset = grp_london.create_dataset("day", data=day_temperature_london_df)
print day_lon_dset[...]
```

This gives me a numpy array. Is there a way to store many dataframes with hierarchy in the same way `.to_hdf` does - it keeps all the properties of the dataframe?

Comment: `h5py` saves `numpy` arrays.  `pandas` has its own methods for saving the whole dataframe.  I think it uses `pytables` instead of `h5py`, though the resulting file can be read with `h5py`.  In effect it saves the dataframe values and indices as separate arrays in some sort of group.  I've explored that structure in earlier SO questions.

Comment: Previous SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165911/how-to-write-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-hdf5-dataset, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173254/how-should-i-use-h5py-lib-for-storing-time-series-data

Comment: An `HDFStore`, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#cookbook-hdf, might give you the most power in storing pandas objects.  I can store things with compound keys like `group/df2', but I can't (so far) create or load just a `group`.

Comment: @hpaulj  yes that's the issue - I can create 'group/df' but cannot call the 'group' only. Also by writing multiple keys with the same group (for some reason) it more than doubles amount of disk space used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm more familiar with `numpy` and `h5py` than `pandas`.  But I was able to create:

```
In [85]: store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
In [86]: store.root
Out[86]: 
/ (RootGroup) ''
  children := []
In [87]: store['df1']=df1
In [88]: store['group/df1']=df1
In [89]: store['group/df2']=df2
```

which can be reloaded and viewed:

```
In [95]: store
Out[95]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store.h5
/df1                  frame        (shape->[3,4])
/group/df1            frame        (shape->[3,4])
/group/df2            frame        (shape->[5,6])

In [96]: store.root
Out[96]: 
/ (RootGroup) ''
  children := ['df1' (Group), 'group' (Group)]
```

`store._handle` shows the file structure in detail.

In a shell I can also look at the file with:

```
1431:~/mypy$ h5dump store.h5 |less
```

Following:

[how should i use h5py lib for storing time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173254/how-should-i-use-h5py-lib-for-storing-time-series-data)

```
In [4]: f1 = h5py.File('store.h5')
In [5]: list(f1.keys())
Out[5]: ['df1', 'group']
In [6]: list(f1['df1'].keys())
Out[6]: ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values']

In [10]: list(f1['group'].keys())
Out[10]: ['df1', 'df2']
In [11]: list(f1['group/df1'].keys())
Out[11]: ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values']
In [12]: list(f1['group/df2'].keys())
Out[12]: ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values']
```

So the `group/df2' key is equivalent to a hierarchy of groups:

```
In [13]: gp = f1['group']
In [15]: gp['df2']['axis0']
Out[15]: <HDF5 dataset "axis0": shape (6,), type "<i8">
[17]: f1['group/df2/axis0']
Out[17]: <HDF5 dataset "axis0": shape (6,), type "<i8">
```

We'd have to dig more into the docs or code of `HDFStore` or `Pytables` to  see if they have an equivalent of `create_group`.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to combine answers, comments and what I found on other pages into this answer.

So yes indeed h5py is no required in my case. Groups can be created by

```
import pandas as pd 
s = pd.HDFStore(test.h5')
s['london/day'] = day_temperature_london_df
s['london/night'] = night_temperature_london_df
```

And each DataFrame can be accessed by:

```
pd.read_hdf('test.h5', 'london/day')
```

But then it is not clear how to read just one group. This can be done by looping though one node like:

```
s = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
[s.select(node._v_pathname) for node in s.get_node('london')]
```

In this case each element of the list become a DataFrame for node 'london'

Structure of the file can be seen by calling `s`

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store_5.h5
/london/day              frame        (shape->[100,2])
/london/night            frame        (shape->[200,1])
```

So this way you should be able to create multiple levels with DataFrames and be able to read them back without losing the column, index etc.