# How to 'zip' and 'unzip' dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in a project where I have different dataframes.
Basically, I have a function that returns 10 dataframes.

I would like to know if would be possible to my function to return all the 10 frames but just in one variable (here my concept of zip).

And then I would take this variable (with the 10 dataframes) and I would pass it to another function, and inside that function I would need to extract all those dataframes to use them.

I can put everything in a list and return it as only one variable, and pass it to second function, but then I would need to access the dataframes by the indices of the list.

What I want is to extract all of them inside the second fuction, without the need to do a loop on each element of the list.

Comment: I think you need `HDF5`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172863/save-multiple-pd-dataframes-with-hierarchy-to-hdf5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ["Mary","John","Alex","Maria","Xavi"]
age = [30,24,29,40,39]
result = list(zip(name,age))
print(result)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of adding comments. Also, your answer is just a code dump; could you explain the code a bit so that others can learn from it?