# Converting NetCDF to HDF5 in Python

Tags: pandas, numpy, hdf5, netcdf, h5py

I have a large NetCDF file with information on variable output from a numerical model (indexed by time). I would like to convert the file to an HDF5 for portability and plotting in the future (also in Python probably matplotlib). I have read a little bit on being able to read HDF5 files with the NetCDF4 module and have been trying that, but I think there is something wrong with the files when I convert them to HDF5. (I know why don't I just keep them in NetCDF if I am using the NetCDF4 module to read and plot them, I was told for portability and storage hdf5 is better? - again resources on this would help too.)

I have separated out the variables into Panda's dataframes and was wondering if there is a way to create datasets in HDF5 that would allow me to plot them in the future? I have used `create_dataset` using h5py, but I don't think it's recording them properly as I am loosing some of the data in the original dataframes. I think I need to know which arguments I need to specify, but I can't find any documentation on it. I also tried `df.to_hdf` but I don't know how to write multiple dataframes to one file. A few of the places I have already looked:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables

https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/index.html#t=HDF5_Users_Guide%2FHDF5_UG_Title%2FHDF5_UG_Title.htm

http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html

I have tried looking up resources, but I haven't had any luck. I know people can be not the nicest on here, but I don't know where else to look and figured someone might know of a resource or have some experience that can help. Really I am just looking to find as much information I can and sometimes people with experience are better than online resources.

EDIT for a code snipet:

```
nc4_type = netCDF4.Dataset(ncfileName) #pulled in prior
station = nc4_type.variables['station']
hs = nc4_type.variables['hs'] #significant wave height*
times = nc4_type.variables['time']
jd = netCDF4.num2date(times[:],times.units)

hsdata = pd.DataFrame(data=hs[:,:], columns=station[:], index=jd)
hf.create_dataset('hs', data = hsdata)
```

My nc dataset.

```
float fp(time, station) ;
                fp:long_name = "  peak frequency (Fp=1/Tp)" ;
                fp:standard_name = "dominant_wave_frequency" ;
                fp:globwave_name = "dominant_wave_frequency" ;
                fp:units = "s-1" ;
                fp:scale_factor = 1.f ;
                fp:add_offset = 0.f ;
                fp:valid_min = 0.f ;
                fp:valid_max = 100.f ;
                fp:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;
                fp:content = "TX" ;
                fp:associates = "time station" ;

 float hs(time, station) ;
                hs:long_name = "spectral estimate of significant wave height" ;
                hs:standard_name = "sea_surface_wave_significant_height" ;
                hs:globwave_name = "significant_wave_height" ;
                hs:units = "m" ;
                hs:scale_factor = 1.f ;
                hs:add_offset = 0.f ;
                hs:valid_min = 0.f ;
                hs:valid_max = 100.f ;
                hs:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;
                hs:content = "TX" ;
                hs:associates = "time station" ;

 int station(station) ;
                station:long_name = "station id" ;
                station:_FillValue = -2147483647 ;
                station:axis = "X" ;


 float th1m(time, station) ;
                th1m:standard_name = "mean_wave_direction" ;
                th1m:globwave_name = "mean_wave_direction" ;
                th1m:units = "degree" ;
                th1m:scale_factor = 1.f ;
                th1m:add_offset = 0.f ;
                th1m:valid_min = 0.f ;
                th1m:valid_max = 360.f ;
                th1m:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;
                th1m:content = "TX" ;
                th1m:associates = "time station" ;
```

Comment: `h5py` just stores `numpy` arrays.  If you need indices, ranges, etc you have to store those as well.   `pandas` use pytables to store all of its arrays

Comment: "I have used `create_dataset` using h5py, but I don't think it's recording them properly as I am loosing some of the data in the original dataframes." This seems to be the actual on-topic issue here. Please provide a code example.

Comment: @hpaulj not very helpful. Could you provide any information on how to do that? Store the indices etc.

Comment: And @Mad Physicist, I say that because when I write it to the HDF5 and then try to view it in my code for plotting, it only has the values and no indexing from the dates or the stations. Let me know if I should post my code where I try to read it.

Comment: `hf.create_dataset('hs', data = hsdata)` stores just the values from the dataframe, not the indices.  In effect it stores `np.array(hsdata)` or equivalently `hsdata.to_numpy()`.

Comment: @hpaulj, I thought that was the point of my question. Again, do you have any information on how to maintain the indexing? I was thinking maybe there is an argument I am missing in `create_dataset`? The dataframe has the dates and stations as the column and row headers, but appears to be lost when I read it in as an hdf5 file using the NetCDF4 module where it becomes a masked array.

Comment: No, there isn't a missing parameter.  You are, I think ignoring some fundamental differences between NETCDF and H5, and between `pandas` and `numpy`.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve what I am asking? See, this is the issue with this forum, people would rather try and tell me I am dumb, than help me solve my problem. Like if what I am doing is not working the way I thought then maybe there is another method that would allow me to maintain the information from a NetCDF to HDF5, but apparently HDF5 just contains arrays and no further metadata? Which I am pretty sure is not true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173254/how-should-i-use-the-h5py-library-for-storing-time-series-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165911/how-to-write-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-hdf5-dataset

Comment: @summer, I'm not familiar with NetCDF, so not exactly sure what you need. If you want the column headers, you can save the data as a NumPy record array (rows will still be rows 0 to N). Record arrays are 2D arrays of mixed data types. HDF5 objects have attributes that might work to hold your metadata.